# Sencha Touch Ext.navigation.View pop to root

Tags: javascript, navigation, sencha-touch-2

I have an Ext.navigation.View in which I have pushed a few views. Certain user interactions require that I go directly back to the top level of the navigation view -- the equivalent of popToRootViewControllerAnimated: on a UINavigationController in iOS.

I have tried various things like:

```
while(navigationView.getItems().getCount() > 1)
    navigationView.pop();
```

and

```
while(navigationView.canPop())
    navigationView.pop();
```

Neither work. The first example seems to put me into an infinite loop which isn't too surprising. The second example only seems to pop one view off.

So the question: What is the proper way to pop to the root view in an Ext.navigation.View in Sencha Touch (version 2 developer preview)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There has been a number of interim methods for achieving this.

The one I was using was to pop a number higher than the number of levels you would ever have e.g.

```
navigationView.pop(10);
```

and that worked fine, but I was never happy with that, but I see they have now introduced a reset method. Which you can call thus...

```
navigationView.reset();
```

Internally within the Sencha source code (see below) you can see that it does a similar job to what @Mithralas said, but just easier to write.

```
// From the Sencha source code
this.pop(this.getInnerItems().length);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
popToRoot: function() {
     this.pop(this.getItems().length - 1);
}
```

Comment: At the time I wrote my question this code wouldn't have worked in the latest developer preview. Since this is now the proper way to do it, I am changing my accepted answer to this.

Comment: The proper way to do it is as of 2.0 is

navigationView.reset()

Answer (score 2):

Ensure to use the NavigationView.reset() method. To make it clear, if your main navigation view is Main, you'd do something like this in the controller:

this.getMain().reset();

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be extending the navigation view with the following:

```
popToRoot: function(destroy)
{
    var navBar = this.getNavigationBar(),
    stackLn = this.stack.length,
    stackRm;

    //just return if we're at root
    if(stackLn <= 1) return;
    //just return if we're already animating
    if(navBar && navBar.animating) return;

    //splice the stack to get rid of items between top and root
    stackRm = this.stack.splice(1, stackLn-2);
    //remove views that were removed from the stack if required
    if(destroy) {
        stackRm.forEach(function(val, idx, arr) {
            this.remove(val, true);
        });
    }
    //clear out back button stack
    navBar.backButtonStack = [];
    //now we can do a normal pop
    this.pop();
}
```

Comment: I posted the question on Sencha's forums which got me the answer that there is a way to set the active item to root, but it would not modify the view stack.

It was at this point I decided to add my own routine to do it. I posted my solution on the Sencha forums as well and hopefully they will add this functionality into Sencha Touch 2.0

Comment: As of Sencha Touch 2 you can just say this.pop(this.getItems().length);

Comment: True. They added that after I posted my solution to them and asked for similar functionality to be included by default.

Comment: I don't know the policy but maybe you should add this to beginning of the answer. We wouldn't want anyone to use this piece of code for current version right?

Comment: I have updated the accepted answer to be the one which references what I understand is the correct way to do it.