# Sencha Touch 2: How to reset navigation view seamlessly

Tags: extjs, navigation, sencha-touch-2

How do I reset a navigation view stack completely, and then push a view?

I have two main user flows in my app: Signup, and Directory.
During signup, I want to animate between views with the typical navigation view animated transitions, but with the navigation bar hidden.  The directory is the same, with the bar showing.

When signup transitions to directory, I want signup views removed from the stack such that the navigation bar is shown without a back button.

So far, I've tried using 
`navigationView.pop();` and `navigationView.reset();`
as mentioned here: [Sencha Touch Ext.navigation.View pop to root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790162/sencha-touch-ext-navigation-view-pop-to-root), followed by ``navigationView.push(newView);

But that results in the the views being popped, yet somehow remaining on the stack.  Using `Ext.Function.defer` to delay my calls to push does not work, either.

I've tried multiple combinations of view hierarchies now to get this transition from Signup to Directory, but nothing seems to work.  When I call `controller.getItems()` after a reset, the items are still there.  What gives?

Here's my current view hierarchy:

```
Ext.define('MobileWebApp.view.Launch', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'launch',
id: 'launch',
config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    baseCls: 'launch',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        id: 'header',
        layout: 'hbox',
        height: '40px',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'plain',
            baseCls: 'logo',
            width: '110px',
            height: '25px'
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 'mainNav',
        xtype: 'navigationview',
        navigationBar: {
            ui: 'neutral',
            hidden: true
        },
        flex: 1
    }
    ]
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a third main navigation view which transitions from the Signup nav to the Directory nav.